# How do you properly pull to a new branch in git using github?

Tags: git, github

Hello I am trying to pull someones updates to a new branch in our project. 
I had stuff I was working on so I stashed it and then created a new branch. Once I created the new branch I did a `git pull origin <branch_name>`

then I got this error:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/bin/subl -w'.
```

It tells me to merge my branch to continue, but I am nervous about messing up my friend's work by merging. Can someone explain to me what is the best way to avoid this problem, what can I do to fix this error?

Much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is probably, uhh, that there was a problem with the editor `/usr/local/bin/subl -w`. Maybe you could start off by typing the command `/usr/local/bin/subl -w` and see what happens. If that fails, as I'm guessing it will, then google 'git editor' to see how to change or fix your git editor setting.

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is related to your `core.editor` setting. In your `.gitconfig` file you probably have a section that looks like this

```
[core]
    editor = '/usr/local/bin/subl -w'
```

But git does not succeed in spawning an editor using that command. You should make sure the editor setting points to a working editor. The simplest way is to remove the entire setting and let git use the default. That should always work.

You can inspect your .gitconfig settings using the command

```
git config --list
```

Your git settings are created from a number of different files, that are in different places depending on your OS. See [the man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES) for starters.